# How to run Integration Tests in CI-Server between Backend and Frontend Projects?

Tags: rest, continuous-integration, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have built a Project separated into backend git repository (node.js rest api) and frontend git repository (angular 4).

I have set up Gitlab-CI to run my tests for each repo. Now I want to make sure my software does not brake when I make changes either in frontend nor in backend.

I came to this idea: When i push my frontend Project, I can clone my actual backend and than run integration tests from FE to BE. On the other way, when I push backend I have to clone my frontend and run the same integration tests again from FE to BE.

Is there maybe other way? I though also about making a new repository and use frontend and backend repos as git submodules?

Answer (score 1):

Since FE does not make sense without BE, you can consider FE testing as integration one.

Basically you test REST API back end with a sort of client that interacts with BE using knowledge of the sevice interface. So your client pretends to be a FE. If your test coverage is good enough you can be sure that the changes in the interface would not break the data exchange mechanism.

However there still could be the changes causing the "message format" modifications (but preserving the mechanism those messages are transfered from DE to FE and back) so that the client would fail to parse those messages or intereprete them.

Thus, I would recommend to run both set of tests on either BE or FE changes and consider FE tests as integration ones.

Comment: yes this i what i have also though about. what do you think about putting this 2 repositorys into one by using git-submodules?

Comment: @Robert this is probably worth doing however I would not put effort on it since it requires some more configuration and some more maintenance but not introduce a lot of extra value.